# What happens when the top-k query does not find enough documents to satisfy k constraint?

Tags: information-retrieval, spatial-query, precision-recall, query-analyzer

I am evaluating the top-k range query using NDCG. Given a spatial area and a query keyword, my top-k range query must return k documents in the given area that are textual relevant to the query keyword.

In my scenario, the range query usually finds only one document to return. But I have to compare this query to another one who can find more objects in the given area, with the same keyword. This is possible because an approach I am testing to improve objects description.

I am not figuring out how to use NDCG to compare these two queries in this scenario. I would like to compare Query A and B using NDCG@5, NDCG@10, but Query A only finds one object. Query A will have high NDCG value because of its lower ability to find more objects (probably the value will be one - the maximum). Query B finds more objects (in my opinion, a better solution) but has a lower NDCG value than query A.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider looking at a different measure, e.g. Recall@10, if you care less about the ranking for your application.

NDCG is a measure designed for web search, where you really want to penalize a system that doesn't return the best item at the topmost result, which is why it has an exponential decay factor. This makes sense for ***navigational queries*** like ``stackoverflow'' you will look quite bad if you don't return this website first.

It sounds like you are building something a little more sophisticated, where the user cares about many results. Therefore, a more recall-oriented measure (that cares about getting multiple things right more than the ranking) may make more sense.

> its lower ability to find more objects

I'd also double-check your implementation of NDCG: you always want to divide by the ideal ranking, regardless of what actually gets returned. It sounds like your Query A returns 1 correct object, but Query B returns more correct objects, but not at high ranks? Either way, you expect Query A to be divided by the DCG of a perfect ranking -- that means 10, 20, or thousands of "correct" objects. It may be that you just don't have enough judgments, and therefore your "perfect ranking" is too small, and therefore you aren't penalizing Query A enough.